# My computer only has a LAN connection, no WAN

Tags: networking

I have a computer here that can connect to the network, but can't connect to the internet.

If I connect the cable to my laptop, it works fine, so it's not the cable.

I've tried changing my IP to both a static IP and a bind in the router.

The strange thing is, if I boot my computer with a live Ubuntu usb drive, it has the same problem; network, but no internet, so I think that rules out any wrong settings.

Can it be that the ethernet adapter is broken in such a way that it only connects to the local network?

Comment: “Can it be that the ethernet adapter is broken in such a way” – No. Please describe your home network, including the make and model of all network devices involved.

Comment: The only network device involved is my router, a Netgear FVS336GV2. Replacing the ethernet adapter with an USB ethernet adapter fixed it, but I still find this a strange issue.

Comment: Have you checked for a BIOS and driver update for the computer?

Comment: No, but it used to work with the current bios, drivers seem irrelevant since it is the same with a different OS.

Comment: Are you sure you are plugging the internet cable in the right slot on the router? This is the most common issue with the router.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Besides, it works when I plug the cable in my laptop.

Comment: You couldn't make a mistake with the laptop, but routers usually have 5 or more slots, where only one is correct. I am certain that the router is causing the trouble. Can you test the connection with any other device (wireless, or LAN) ?

Comment: Recap:I have a cable coming from my router to my computer. If I plug the cable in my laptop, it works. If I plug the same cable in my computer, I only have LAN access. If I use a different OS, I still have only LAN. If I plug the cable in my usb Ethernet adapter in my computer, I also have internet access.

Comment: Desktop... I see. Firewall rule that blacklists your desktops network card's MAC address then. You can try accessing those rules on your routers local ip address (you don't need internet for that).

Comment: You can also try plugging wan connected ethernet cable directly to your desktop. Just to test my theory before digging into router settings.